# dump Protobuf class variables to a list/dict and swap keys

Tags: python, class, protocol-buffers

i'm working with the lovely Protobuf (*cough*) and i'm running into an odd problem: instead of returning 'value' as a member of the 'Metric' class in the MQTT message, it is returning, through the `oneof` declaration, keys like `boolean_value`, `string_value`, &c.  since this is supposed to be Sparkplug B message, the key *should* be just `value`.  this is breaking our MQTT code for handling messages as well as confuses the hell out of me because Sparkplug B is kinda the bread-and-butter/raison-d'etre of Protobuf, is it not?

at any rate, since i have to move forward, i just figured i'd do a key-swap after dumping the class variables/properties to a list, like so:

```py
def on_message():
  inboundPayload = sparkplug_b_pb2.Payload()
  inboundPayload.ParseFromString(msg.payload) #<-- msg is the MQTT message
  #  let's see what's in the 'metric` part of the payload
  for metric in inboundPayload.metrics:
    print(metric)
    #  alias: 19
    #  timestamp: shpak-of-numbers
    #  datatype: 11
    #  is_null: false
    #  boolean_value: true  #<-- this key should be 'value' but it isn't, so let's just
    #    replace the key with some hoop-jumping  ↓

    metric['value'] = metric.pop(list(metric.items())[-1]  #<-- in concept test, works; here: no

    #  blah blah rest of code block
```

as the comment says, when i tested this with a simple dict, it worked just fine.  but when i dropped it into the code here, it tanks when i try to replace the key.

can someone please point out what i'm doing wrong?  my intuition says it has something to do with the `metric.items()` part, but, i'll admit, my Python chops are still wobbly working with the Protobuf classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with Sparkplug B but it appears well-documented.

Here's one copy of the [Metric](https://github.com/Cirrus-Link/Sparkplug/blob/56df2ff8fbf0dd11b009152b4606debe31dd9468/sparkplug_b/sparkplug_b.proto#L161C5-L161C5) message:

```protobuf
message Metric {

    optional string   name          = 1;
    optional uint64   alias         = 2;
    optional uint64   timestamp     = 3;
    optional uint32   datatype      = 4;
    optional bool     is_historical = 5;
    optional bool     is_transient  = 6;
    optional bool     is_null       = 7;
    optional MetaData metadata      = 8;
    optional PropertySet properties = 9;

    oneof value {
        uint32   int_value                      = 10;
        uint64   long_value                     = 11;
        float    float_value                    = 12;
        double   double_value                   = 13;
        bool     boolean_value                  = 14;
        string   string_value                   = 15;
        bytes    bytes_value                    = 16;
        DataSet  dataset_value                  = 17;
        Template template_value                 = 18;
        MetricValueExtension extension_value    = 19;
    }
}
```

As you can see from this definition, `value` is a `oneof` type.

Here's the [documentation for `oneof`'s in Python](https://protobuf.dev/reference/python/python-generated/#oneof).

The `value` field is effectively polymorphic.

In order to represent such union types in Protobuf, `oneof`'s may be used.

In your example, this message's `value` contains a boolean. In order to disambiguate the possible types, each must be given a unique name. In this case `boolean_value` is used.

The code is as-explained in the documentation:

```
assert metric.HasField("boolean_value")
print(metric.boolean_value)
```

Other messages may contain other types and so you need to cover them all.

One quirk (!) of the Python (there are multiple language implementations|SDKs of Protobufs) is that the `oneof` field name, in this case `value` is **not** preserved in the Python object structure. Instead the fields that comprise it e.g. `boolean_value` are part of the parent (e.g. `metric`) type.

So `metric.boolean_value` not `metric.value.boolean_value`.

Aside:

> It can be frustrating adopting new technologies but, Protocol Buffers is successfully used quite widely. No documentation is perfect, but the [`protobuf.dev`](https://protobuf.dev/) is decent and, if there's content missing, the authors are responsive to feedback.

###### Update

The best practice when using Protocol Buffers regardless of SDK is to map to|from internal (business logic) types and protobuf messages types. In your case, your business logic would have a representation of Sparkplug's `Metric` types, let's call it `InternalMetric`:

```py
import sparkplugb_pb2


payload = sparkplugb_pb2.Payload()
metric = payload.metrics.add()

class InternalMetric:
    def __init__(self,m: sparkplugb_pb2.Payload_Metric):
        self.name=m.name
        self.alias=m.alias
        
        # Not exhaustive but by way of example...
        if m.HasField("int_value"):
            self.value=m.int_value
        if m.HasField("boolean_value"):
            self.value=m.boolean_value

    def __str__(self):
        return f"name: {self.name} alias: {self.alias} value: {self.value}"
    

metric.name = "Foo"
metric.alias = 1

# First time using boolean_value
metric.boolean_value = True

print(metric)

# Create a new InternalMetric
i=InternalMetric(metric)
print(i)

# In practice this would be a different Metric instance
# But as an exemplar
# Second time using int_value
metric.int_value = 23

# Create a new InternalMetric
i=InternalMetric(metric)
print(i)
```

Yields:

```
name: "Foo"
alias: 1
boolean_value: true

name: Foo alias: 1 value: True
name: Foo alias: 1 value: 23
```

Comment: i understand literally ALL of that.  the spBv1.0 spec calls for ` value` to be returned as a key, not `boolean_value`.  the point is i need to replace the returned key `boolean_value` (or string_ or int_ or float_...) with just `value`.  i guess i wasn't clear enough: the last line where i am trying to swap keys is not working.  i want to know why.

Comment: clearer head today.  deleted non-useful comment.  but my original question still stands:  **why does the key replacement line of code not work?**  i accept that Python doesn't keep the original key (stupid, in the context of a standardized messaging protocol, IMO) so i just want to swap it out internally because it's far easier to work with in modularized code.

Comment: `metric` isn't a dict so you can't `metric['value']`, `metric.pop` or `metric.items`. If you `type(metric)`, you'll get that it's a `sparkplugb_pb2.Metric` (or similar) class. And, in fact, is generated by the meta class defined in `sparkplugb_pb2`. The best practice for business logic is to represent protobuf messages types using user-defined types and to map to|from these. I'll provide an example in my answer.

Comment: i thought you could use `items()` to pull class properties into a list, from which you could then `pop`.  thank you for clarifying that.  as for the mapping to a new internal class, that's a new one on me.  so thank you again for a VERY instructive answer!  not only answered the hell out of my question, but made me a better coder.  +1 is insufficient.  :)

Comment: ONE HOUR LATER:  as i look at this again, the solution seems obvious.  what a fantastic principle!  i am so grateful!  thank you.